# Work around to getting Backup and Migrate to work with Acquia Dev Cloud?

Tags: drush, backups, acquia-cloud

Currently, when you host a site onto Acquia Dev Cloud, they disable the ability to install backup and migrate module due to it affecting their "server" setup. This proves to be a big nuisance when trying to create a quick backup of a site and to even make scheduled hourly backups. The suggest us to use the Acquia platform to do backups, but it's totally inefficient since it cannot schedule your own backup times. And doing this via drush is troublesome if you just want to do a quick backup because you wanted to make a change on a site just in case it breaks it.

How would one go around this problem of backing up a site with Acquia dev cloud?

Comment: How did you try to install backup and migrate there (I haven't faced the issue at doing it from command line) ? And who replied to you ? Non technical are sometimes in first line of support and may give non sense replies.

Answer (score 1):

The best is enable your access to the command line to their server.

For this you need to store your public ssh_key in your profile on their platform.

Then to find the exact server and username to connect do :

- Sign in to the Acquia Cloud interface.
- Select your application and
  environment.
- In the menu to the left, click Users and Keys, to see your exact command :
  [image: screenshot]

What follows is using drush ... but wait ... you can automate the use of drush : I explain.

Once logged, you can use drush from the command line, like this :

`cd dev/livedev/docroot`

`drush ard`

Since you have access to the command line, you can also use scp to transfer your backup.

By the way you won't have the possibility to access crontab -e there, however, you can write a script and execute from your computer to connect via ssh, do the backup, and get it using scp.

Once this script is written, you can use the cron from your computer to execute it every hour if you want.

That script would look like :

`` cd ~/dev/livedev/docroot
drush ard
cd drush-backups/archive-dump/
cd `ls -Art | tail -n 1` 
mv `ls -Art | tail -n 1` ~/last_backup.tgz ``

You can store it remotely as ~/backup.sh locally in your cron you put

`ssh -t -t yourlogin@youraddress '~/backup.sh && exit' && scp yourlogin@youraddress:~/last_backup.tgz /home/yourself`

For an explanation of the -t -t, see https://serverfault.com/questions/224307/ssh-fails-to-execute-remote-command-when-run-from-cron-bash-script-works-from

If any other issue, with ssh from cron, please watch also : https://serverfault.com/questions/186448/crontab-to-run-bash-script-ssh-command-in-it-not-working

Another solution is to use the scheduled job from their interface, as explained there : https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-cloud/manage/cron

If any other problem please comment.

Comment: paying 20k for acquia on an Enterprise account is really stupid that i can't even use back up migrate.

Comment: Myself I never use Backup and Migrate ... using that, makes sense only when you don't have ssh and drush access. I tell you here how all the professionals are working : They go on drush ard + scp  or similar stuff ... and eventually automate that.

Comment: what if you wanted to revert to a previous change an hour ago? you'd have to make sure your custom script does that. also ssh is not friendly for non users of the terminal if you want to revert.

Comment: This was not the question to be covered here but, same fashion to act is ok, because drush provides the way to restore backups.

Be aware that Acquia platform is not built, in my opinion, for people like wordpress developers, who know just a bit of css, html and are scared of the command line.

That's why my first answer what about automating drush with cron, and then verifying if you really couldn't not install backup and migrate ... indeed you can.

Answer (score 1):

Correction : The install of Backup And Migrate works.

Follow the procedure explained before to enable ssh access.
Once logged in, do

`cd ~/dev/livedev/docroot`

Then

`drush -y en backup_migrate`

That's all. I tried. It just works. Here is screenshot :
[image]

Comment: i ssh into the acquia dev server and tried to enable it via drush, but it does not work. see: http://prntscr.com/fjc695 it throws errors. "exception 'DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException' with message 'Table backup_migrate_profiles already exists.' "

Comment: run :
drush -y pmu backup_migrate && drush -y en backup_migrate

That will clean up the db first.

Comment: nope. still throws the error.